# Appending to a list pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am currently facing the following issue.

I have code that essentially has the following cases:

```
val toList = this.toString.match {
  case "" => List[MyType]()
  case _  => this.val :: this.prev.toList
}
```

Obviously not exact but its the general gist. It works fine but I want the values appended to the list in the reverse order. Is there any good way to do this? Intellij throws errors if I try to reverse the order and do

```
this.prev.toList :: this.val
```

and also if I try to use operations like ++. Is what I'm trying to do impossible based on the structure of my class?

The specific errors I get involve "cannot resolve ::" or whatever symbol I use when I try to put this.prev.toList before this.val.

And yes the "this" aren't necessary- I included it to hopefully make my problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` adds an element at the beginning of this list

```
scala> 1 :: List(2,3)
List(1, 2, 3)
```

`+:` is the equivalent of `::`

```
scala> 1 +: List(2,3)
List(1, 2, 3)
```

`:+` append element at the end of the list

```
scala> List(1,2) :+ 3
List(1, 2, 3)
```

However the cost of prepending on List is O(1) but the appending one is O(n)!

For "numerous" collections you could consider other datastructure like Vector:

> Vector provides very fast append and prepend

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector

Comment: Thanks! I usually use vector but the assignment calls for using a list so I decided not to mess around with different collections.

Comment: If the assignment force you to use `List` maybe is trying to push you to approach the solution using `::` and recursion...

Answer (score 0):

You can append with this method `:+`:

```
this.prev.toList :+ this.val  // is `val` really then name?
```

But keep in mind that appending to a `List` can be very inefficient for long lists.